# I'm using asp.net for creating Webforms, but Visual Studio is behaving inconsistently

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I've used Visual Studio for C# development flawlessly for years, but am new to ASP.net.  I've been making copies of some of the contacts and about pages as a jumpstart for my pages, and have made the partial classes unique.  Sometimes things work great, but other times when double clicking on a button instead of it creating a method stub as usual, it does not do anything and I seem to get an alternate button control that is similar but does not function quite the same.  As far as I can tell I did things consistently, but may have missed something subtle.  Sorry I am not sure how to state my problem more succinctly.

You can tell this button worked fine as it has an OnClick method defined:

```
asp:Button ID="btnMedSelect" runat="server" OnClick="btnMedSelect_Click" Text="Select"
```

This one did not work:

```
asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button"
```

Some of the preceding files are different and "Inherits" files are different.

Answer (score 0):

I think Visual Studio was getting confused as I was copying some of their sample pages as a start for my own instead of Adding new Web Forms from the menu.

I have not had a problem since I stopped copying the sample pages.